# Cyanamide mesomeric contributors

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ions, stability, resonance

Which form of the cyanamide ion is more stable?

As per the resonance rules, I find both of them equally stable as number of bonds is the same, more electronegative atom has negative charge and so on. Is my conclusion right?

[image: Cyanamide mesomeric contributors]

Comment: Can you rotate the picture anticlockwise?

Comment: The original picture is oriented properly. It got twisted when I uploaded it here, and I've got no idea of how to make it straight